# External Parameters to Java Rest Assured Application

Tags: java, junit, rest-assured

I need to know if it is possible get my **test parameters** in Rest Assured / Junit from an external file.

That is, instead of putting inside the class, put in another location, file (for example):

Example:

```
public class Name extends Base {
     private final String UrlString= "resource";
   @Test
   public void teste() {
               ResponseDTO responseDTO = given()
               .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
               .headers("utoken", utoken)
               .pathParam("name",name) //move from place
               .when()
               .get(UrlString)
               .then()
               .statusCode(is(statusok))
               .extract().as(ResponseDTO.class);
               validade(responseDTO);
   }          
   //...code
```

Comment: Which parameter you need to be picked from the file ? `utoken` and `name` ? You can use java properties file and search a bit online about that. How to use properties file in java rest assured application

Comment: Thank you for your information Nagaraj Tantri. I need to pick up the configurability (header, parameters) and wanted to optimize by putting in some file, or data provider. Are you an example to show me?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `org.springframework:spring-test` dependency, one easy option is to use `@TestPropertySource` annotation, like so:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test-application.properties")
public class SmokeIT {

  @Value("${test.url}")
  private String testUrl;

  @Test
  public void shouldReturnOkWhenGet() {
    when().get(testUrl).then().statusCode(200);
  }
}
```